# Rename-Item - Possible syntax error with Environmental Variable?

Tags: powershell

Alright guys, I'm sure I'm doing something stupid here, but I've spent about 15 minutes looking for this already, and haven't found anyone using an environmental variable along with the "Rename-Item" command.  Can anyone give me a quick "Why didn't you just do ?"

`$test = $env:APPDATA
Rename-Item -Force -LiteralPath $test\testFolder\test.txt -NewName "testWORKED.txt"`

UPDATE: I have a working version now, but it does not like the spaces...  Anyone have any tips on why a space in the UNC would break this even with double quotes around it?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your code should work. Dont see why not

Comment: @ArcSet, [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2gzy6Jgps5mNU5FdWhxYkZPS00/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I found very strange the remark that the whitespace in a variable is affecting the parameter value e.g. in the `Rename-Item`, so I did the following `Get-Item -LiteralPath $Env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip` which returns an item. Try @BillKleinhomer have you tried such concepts elsewhere? Maybe also raise the trace levels and look in there?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```
$folderPath = Join-Path $env:APPDATA "testFolder"
$filePath = Join-Path $folderPath "test.txt"    
Rename-Item $filePath -NewName "testWORKED.txt"
```

.. but your code works on my computer.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with my user path having a space in it.

`Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Users\Bill Kleinhomer\AppData\Roaming\testFolder\test.txt' 
does not exist.`

Comment: Yep, that could be it. Use `"$test\testFolder\test.txt"`, then. Or `Join-Path` :)

Comment: this is the error... [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2gzy6Jgps5mNU5FdWhxYkZPS00/view?usp=sharing)